# Migration from Magento 1.14 to Magento 2.0 - Enterprise Edition for both

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-2.0

We have an enterprise application running on Magento 1.14
Our new requirement is to **migrate EE 1.14 to EE 2.0**. Going through the links available online, I could not find a complete solution or steps involved for migration. 
It may include real time key points like

- How to migrate site settings and configuration?
- Migrate categories, products, customers, order and other details ?
- Migrate other data ?

It would be great if someone could guide on a good starting point and what would be the real time steps involved for migration from 1.14 EE to 2.0 EE ?

Comment: Please be consistent in your questions. Are you referring to Magento 1.4.2 CE or Magento EE 1.14 ? You're using two different versions in your question.

Comment: It's for enterprise edition for both versions

Comment: There's no EE 1.4.2.

Comment: Kindly ignore my typo. Question details updated

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be very difficult since there was a complete structural/implementation change between 1.x.x and 2.0.0 It could easily take over a week to make all of the needed changes to the structure and any extensions that you are using may not be available. It is not a simple shift so there are likely very few guides on this process. It would be impossible to show you how to do all of the changes in this alone. I would suggest learning Magento 2 from tutorials and then going from there.

Comment: I understand that this is a lot of work. But i you could highlight some general guidelines or steps involved, would be great.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html